# Append CKEditor in div tag using onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

I'm creating a blog website, I want to add this(CKEditor) or any text editor(WYSIWYG) to my form tag. I search a lot on all well known platform. but no answer I found.
The method I am using is that I wrote the script. When I clicked, I typed the textarea tag code in the quote of my script but Simple textarea tags are added to my code. But the editor script is not loading. How do I load a full functional editor on a click event?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>CKEditor</title>
      <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h3>Document Load (Working)</h3>
   <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
   <script>
           CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
   </script>            
   <h3>When Append (not working)</h3>
   <button onclick="addCodeEditor('Editor')" class="btn btn-primary">Editor</button>   
   <div id="additionalElement"></div>
   <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2' );
   </script>
 </body>
</html>

   <script>
 var codeEditorCount;
 function addCodeEditor(Editor){
    var div = document.getElementById('additionalElement');
    div.innerHTML += '<textarea name="editor2"></textarea>';
    codeEditorCount++;
 }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work. I made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/cbuzmfpL/2/

 I don't know why it shows an error here in the code example but the fiddle works.

```js
document.getElementById('editor1').style.display = 'none';

function myFunction() {
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<button type="text" onClick="myFunction()">
Click me
</button>
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor 4.
</textarea>
```

Comment: And how to replace WYSIWYG editor. if you know the script mention here

Comment: Updated my fiddle. Now you have a editor1 loaded at start and if you click the button the editor is replaced by the editor2. See that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/cbuzmfpL/4/

Comment: Thank you, Bernhard. will you tell me how to replace WYSIWYG?
CKeditor.replace is a command for CKEditor.
which command use for WYSIWYG?

Comment: Made a new fiddle. Now you can change the Textarea WISIWIG by clicking on the button. See: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/xfwgaL60/3/